# Cannot mix incompatible Qt library

Tags: linux, qt, qt5, fedora

Установил ShotCut. Он даунгрейдил какие-то библиотеки Qt5.

Потом оказалось, что некоторые программы не запускаются

```
FATAL: Cannot mix incompatible Qt library (version 0x50902) with this library (version 0x50901)
```

Программу удалил, но ошибка осталась. Как я понимаю, конфликт из-за разных версий Qt

Comment: как на счёт `dnf update` ?

Comment: update, или update qt5* ?

Comment: https://docs.fedoraproject.org/f27/system-administrators-guide/package-management/DNF.html

Comment: К сожалению не могу обновить систему. Мало места в системном каталоге. Задумываюсь о новом винте. Ну а пока хоть как-то разобраться с Qt5. Ведь программа работала...

Comment: `dnf reinstall qt` ?

Comment: Не помогло ни dnf reinstall qt, ни dnf reinstall qt5* Зато помогло dnf update qt5, но предварительно dnf autoremove, какие-то зависимости мешали обновлению без autoremove.